# Having trouble converting a uri to bitmap,getting bytes,compressing- inside asynctask and then uploading to server

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask

Hi am working on app that uploads an images to firebase either through the taking a picture with a device or uploading an existing image from device. The latter works. However for taking a picture, my code stops at point where i am converting uri to bitmap but not sure why.
Error "    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference"

I know its basic but i have been struggling with it for a few days, kindly help.

LogCat

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:646)
        at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:1101)
        at rungene.com.forsale.PostFragment$ImageResizeBackground.doInBackground(PostFragment.java:202)
        at rungene.com.forsale.PostFragment$ImageResizeBackground.doInBackground(PostFragment.java:173)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
10-23 20:56:26.094 788-788/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 1122 num clients 11
```

Post Fragment:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import rungene.com.forsale.models.Post;
import rungene.com.forsale.util.UniversalImageLoader;

public class PostFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment  implements PhotoDialogFragment.PhotoListener{

    private static final String TAG = "PostFragment";

    private EditText postTitle,postDescription,postPrice,postCountry,postStateProvince,postCity,postEmail;
    private ImageView postImage;
    private Button buttonPost;
    private ProgressBar progressBarPost;
    private Bitmap selectedBitmap;
    private Uri selectedUri;
    private byte[] uploadBytes;
    private double mProgress=0;


    @Override
    public void getImageBitMap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getImageBitMap: assign image to imageview");
        postImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //assign to global variables
        selectedBitmap = bitmap;

        selectedUri = null;


    }

    @Override
    public void getImagePath(Uri imagePath) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getImagePath: setting image to imageview");
        UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imagePath.toString(),postImage);
        //assign to global variables
        selectedBitmap = null;
        selectedUri = imagePath;

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_fragment,container,false);

        postTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.postTitle);
        postDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.postDescription);
        postPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.postPrice);
        postCountry = view.findViewById(R.id.postCountry);
        postStateProvince = view.findViewById(R.id.postStateProvince);
        postCity = view.findViewById(R.id.postCity);
        postEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.postEmail);
        postImage = view.findViewById(R.id.postImage);
        buttonPost = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonPost);
        progressBarPost = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarPost);


        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

        photoDialog();

        return view;

    }

    private void photoDialog(){
        postImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening upload photo dialog");

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image View Tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                PhotoDialogFragment photoDialogFragment = new PhotoDialogFragment();
                photoDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),getString(R.string.photo_select));
                photoDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(PostFragment.this,1);

            }
        });

        buttonPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attemptng to post");

                if (!isEmpty(postTitle.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(postDescription.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(postPrice.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(postCountry.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(postStateProvince.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(postCity.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(postEmail.getText().toString())){
                    //if we have a bitmap and no uri
                    if (selectedBitmap != null && selectedUri==null){

                        uploadPhotoFirebase(selectedBitmap);

                    }
                    //we have no bitmap but uri
                    else if (selectedBitmap==null && selectedUri!= null){
                        uploadPhotoFirebase(selectedUri);

                    }


                }else {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please fill all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void uploadPhotoFirebase(Bitmap bitmap) {

        Log.d(TAG, "uploadPhotoFirebase: uploading a new bitmap to storage");



        ImageResizeBackground imageResizeBackground = new ImageResizeBackground(bitmap);
        Uri uri = null;
        imageResizeBackground.execute(uri);

    }

    private void uploadPhotoFirebase(Uri uriImagePath) {

        Log.d(TAG, "uploadPhotoFirebase: uploading new uri to storage");

        ImageResizeBackground imageResizeBackground = new ImageResizeBackground(null);
        imageResizeBackground.execute(uriImagePath);

    }



    public class ImageResizeBackground extends AsyncTask<Uri,Integer,byte[]>{
        Bitmap mBitmap;

        public ImageResizeBackground(Bitmap bitmap) {

            if (mBitmap!=null){
                this.mBitmap = bitmap;
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Compressing image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showProgressBar();

        }

        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Uri... params) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: started.");

            if(mBitmap == null){

                try{


                    mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), params[0]);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            byte[] bytes = null;

            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + mBitmap.getByteCount() / 1000000 );
            bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(mBitmap, 100);
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + bytes.length / 1000000 );
            return bytes;
        }





        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
            super.onPostExecute(bytes);
            uploadBytes = bytes;
            hideProgressBar();

            //execute the upload task
            implementingUploadTask();
        }

    }
    private void implementingUploadTask(){

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "uploading the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         final String postId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();

         final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("posts/users"
                 + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +"/"+postId +"post_image" );


        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(uploadBytes);

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Post success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //inserting the download url into the firebase database
                Uri uriFirebase = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: firebase download uri"+uriFirebase.toString());

                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                Post post = new Post();
                post.setCity(postCity.getText().toString());
                post.setContact_email(postEmail.getText().toString());
                post.setCity(postCity.getText().toString());
                post.setPost_id(postId);
                post.setDescription(postDescription.getText().toString());
                post.setImage(uriFirebase.toString());
                post.setState_province(postStateProvince.getText().toString());
                post.setCountry(postCountry.getText().toString());
                post.setPrice(postPrice.getText().toString());
                post.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                databaseReference.child(getString(R.string.node_users))
                        .child(postId)
                        .setValue(post);

                resetFields();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could not upload!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                double currentProgress = (100*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());

                if (currentProgress>(mProgress+15)){

                    mProgress = (100*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onProgress: upload is "+mProgress +"% done");

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mProgress+" % ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });


    }

    public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality){

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality,stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();


    }



    private void resetFields(){
        UniversalImageLoader.setImage("",postImage);
        postTitle.setText("");
        postDescription.setText("");
        postPrice.setText("");
        postCountry.setText("");
        postStateProvince.setText("");
        postCity.setText("");
        postEmail.setText("");
        postEmail.setText("");

    }

    private void showProgressBar(){
        progressBarPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void hideProgressBar(){

        if (progressBarPost.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            progressBarPost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }



    /**
     * Return true if the @param is null
     * @param string
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isEmpty(String string){
        return string.equals("");
    }
}
```

PhotoDialogFragment:

```
package rungene.com.forsale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PhotoDialogFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
    private static final String TAG = "PhotoDialogFragment";
    private static final  int pickRequestCode = 12;
    private static final int cameraRequestCode = 13;


    public interface PhotoListener{
        void getImagePath(Uri imagePath);
        void getImageBitMap(Bitmap bitmap);

    }
    PhotoListener photoListener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selectphoto_dialog,container,false);

        TextView textPhoneMemory = view.findViewById(R.id.textPhoneMemory);
        textPhoneMemory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Accessing phone memory");



                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,pickRequestCode);
            }
        });

        TextView textTakePhoto = view.findViewById(R.id.textTakePhoto);

        textTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Starting camera");

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,cameraRequestCode);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //results when selecting a photo form gallery

        if (requestCode==pickRequestCode && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: image uri"+uri);
            //send Uri to post fragment and dismiss dialog.
            photoListener.getImagePath(uri);
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
        //results when taking a photo with camera.

        else if (requestCode==cameraRequestCode && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK ){

            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Done taking photo");

            Bitmap bitmap;

            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            //send the bitmap to Postfragment and dismiss dialog.

            photoListener.getImageBitMap(bitmap);
            getDialog().dismiss();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {

        try {
            photoListener =(PhotoListener)getTargetFragment();

        }catch (ClassCastException e){
            Log.d(TAG, "onAttach:ClassCastException "+e.getMessage());

        }

        super.onAttach(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First

```
public class ImageResizeBackground extends AsyncTask<Uri,Integer,byte[]>
```

You don't appear to use the Uri anywhere so why not change that to Void
and stop passing Null in as it does not require a parameter to execute()

Second

You should be checking that the data returned is not null before accessing it in onActivityResult as it can be null.

Lastly, don't assume the data is a URI. Put a breakpoint and see what it is returning. You may be getting a something different. Without knowing the OS you are running and flow you are going, I can only assume that data is a Uri. Because if everything was done completely right, it most likely would be. But see if it is in an Extras instead of the data directly as well.

Comment: If that is the case, why are you doing uri = null and then execute(uri) you are basically passing null.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However i would need the uri inside the ondoingBacgroud: mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), params[0]);  passing void brings problems. i have included data!=null on activityresult but the error persists

Comment: but my whole point of having the async task was to run this line on background`mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), params[0]);`  if i pass void on Uri i may not be able to execute it.